# An installation script in a Docker's container fails due to xz command

Tags: virtual-machine, docker, xz

I am trying to install PredictProtein for Docker from [here](https://store.docker.com/community/images/bromberglab/predictprotein).
The script for installing the database used by PredictProtein downloads the data as a `.txz` file.

After downloading, the script attempts to decompress the file.
This fails, yielding the error message

```
/usr/local/bin/setupdb: line 15: xz: command not found
```

Why does it fail? And how could I solve this?

I use Docker version 17.12.1-ce; I run it inside an Ubuntu 16.04.3 VM, using VirtualBox

The script (copied for within the container) is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d /usr/share/rostlab-data/ ]; then
        echo "Removing current database..."
        rm -rf /usr/share/rostlab-data/
fi

mkdir /usr/share/rostlab-data/
cd /usr/share/rostlab-data/

echo "Downloading database release..."
wget -O rostlab-data.txz "http://www.rostlab.org/services/ppmi/download_file?format=gzip&file_to_download=db"

echo "Extracting..."
xz -d rostlab-data.txz
tar xvf rostlab-data.tar
rm -f rostlab-data.tar

echo "Done."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the xz command isn't found, the tool probably isn't installed. If the container is based on ubuntu (it probably isn't) it would be installed, making me guess it's based on alpine.

Try installing xz!

```
apk add xz
```

Or if you are editing the Dockerfile, simply add a RUN statement early in the file.

Comment: You mean I should add this command to the installation script?

Comment: If you are in the container with a terminal (interactively) you can simply type it out before you run your script. Otherwise add it as one of the first lines to your Dockerfile "RUN apk add xz"

Comment: I tried `docker run  ecbeaec0320f sudo  apk add xz` but I got the error `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"sudo\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

(ecbeaec0320f is the Image ID)

Comment: Don't use sudo with alpine. Can you link the Dockerfile you are using?

Comment: Also https://training.play-with-docker.com/ops-stage1/ run the first 2 tutorials under Hands-on-learning, and try to understand package manager commands in linux (apt-get in ubuntu and apk in alpine).

Comment: Very well, I'll try them, thanks.
I downloaded this image via
`docker pull bromberglab/predictprotein`

Comment: Also, the container is ubuntu based, not alpine:
`docker exec my_predictprotein  cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial`

Comment: But if this is ubuntu rather than alpine, I guess I should use apt-get rather than apk - however when I use 
`docker run ecbeaec0320f apt-get install xz`
I get 
`Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package xz`

Comment: hey you need to do a apt-get update && apt-get upgrade first! Then you can do the apt-get install xz